# Does GWT 2.5+ have an "Authentication Framework"?

Tags: java, session, authentication, gwt

Does the modern (2.5+) version of GWT have an "authentication framework"? That is, some kind of security framework built around session auth & management? I would need this framework to be responsible for securely setting cookies/session vars upon successful login, and clear them upon successful log out.

If not, what do GWT developers typically use for auth? [Shiro](http://shiro.apache.org/)? Would something like [filter-based auth](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/web.1111/e13718/servlet.htm) be appropriate or are there better frameworks? If so, what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GWT once compiled is all javascript. 
You need something on the server-side checking your roles and authorizations. 
There are several options to implement security. One common paradigm is use Spring security on the server side, and onModuleLoad / EntryPoint class of your GWT application, make a call to the server-side proxy to check / authentication and authorization status.
If you get valid response back, continue loading the app, otherwise navigate to the error / login page. Needless to say secure the rest of the proxies and any other services you are exposing, as well.

Comment: Thanks @Neocy (+1) - would Shiro or ESAPI be good candidates for server-side auth?

Comment: Although I havent personally worked with either of those two, quick glance through 10 min tutorial on Shiro, I think is a good candidate for server side authorization. Shiro being a Apache project, also helps.